# Cheapest way from USA to Venezuela?

Tags: usa, budget, venezuela, california

I live in California and I'm trying to find cheap ways to get to Venezuela.

Roundtrip Plane tickets seem to hover around the $1500 area.  I've found a route through Florida to Puerto Rico to Venezeula that is a little cheaper, but not by much.

I am not ruling out any methods of travel, so I don't mind working a little bit on a ship - if anyone knows any connections.

Answer (score 4):

I live in Venezuela, and there's always direct flights from Miami to Maiquetia. 1500USD is expensive but that's the price. Use this site, it's like Expedia.com but in Latin America and works in USA too.

http://www.despegar.com/

To Maracaibo 934 USD. To Maiquetia (Caracas) 600 USD.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind ship travel then check out this website: http://www.flightlesstravel.com

But from my research and depending from where in California and when you want to travel I have found plane tickets advertising round trip for ~$970